# how to negate search in intellij structural search

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, structural-search

How can i exclude terms from intellij's structure search? (NOT text or regex seach!)

for example, using the annotated field template, let's say i want to add `@Lazy` to all occurrences of `@Autowired` for fields of type X?

That means I want to match:

```
@Autowired
private X x;
```

as well as

```
@Autowired
@Getter
Private X x;
```

but not

```
@Lazy
@Autowired
Private X x;
```

I understood from the manual how to match positively by adding conditional `text=...` to the elements, but not how to add a negative.

Edit1:
the reason a regex is not the answer (as suggested in a comment), is because the Structural search matches things like different annotations between the annotation i'm searching for and the field, also it matches any access prefix on the field, etc.

If I move  from structured to regex/text search find/replace, then i will have many other problems.

Comment: You could probably do a multiline regex match with something like `/\@AutoWired\nprivate\s.*$/m` and `/@Autowired\n@Getter\nPrivate\s.*$/m`

Comment: But this lose the ability of being a structural search. (i've updated the question to make this clear)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `@$Lazy$` annotation to the search template with a text filter `Lazy` and a count filter `[0,0]`. This will only find elements that do not have the `@Lazy` annotation.

Comment: thanks! feel bad that i missed `count` staring at me right there :) but learned that i can use the annotation name directly.